# Double registration(As User/As Company)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I write a new ASP.NET MVC 5 application and I have some problems with the authentication. I want to have two registration and login forms (for users and for companies). I use the basic table ApplicationUser for Users and make my own table CompaniesAccountModel for companies. But the problem comes when I use the UserManager and SignInManager. I can't modify them to work with CompaniesAccountModel. Here you are some code.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult CompanyRegister()
{
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CompanyRegister([Bind(Include = "CompanyName, Password, Email, ConfirmPassword")] CompanyAccountModel model)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.CompanyAccountModels.Add(model);
         db.SaveChanges();

         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
     }

     // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
     return View(model);
}
```

and

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult CompanyLogin(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> CompanyLogin(CompanyLoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.CompanyName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I want to use the UserManager and SignInManager for the companies registration and login. If someone have an idea how to do this, it would be well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily customize authentication process for your company users. And use it side by side with existing method for ordinary users. Consider this example as a clue:

```
public ActionResoult CompanyLogin(CompanyLoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    // imaging you have own company manager, completely independent from identity
    // you could check validity of company by own preferred logic  
    if(_companyManager.IsValid(model))         
    {
        // company is valid, going to authenticate
        var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
        new[] 
        {
            // adding following 2 claim just for supporting default antiforgery provider
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, model.CompanyName),
            new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),

            // an optional claim you could omit this 
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.CompanyName),
            // add this role to differentiate from ordinary users
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Company"),                 
            // you could even add some role
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "AnotherRole"),
            // and so on
        },
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Identity is sign in user based on claim don't matter 
        // how you generated it Identity 
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
            new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);

        // auth is succeed, 
        return RedirectToAction("MyAction"); 
     }
     ModelState.AddModelError("", "We could not authorize you :(");
     return View();
}
```

Since we injected our logic to Identity, we don't need to do extra thing at all.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult MySecretAction()
{
    // all authorized users could use this method don't matter how has been authenticated
    // we have access current user principal by calling also
    // HttpContext.User
 }

 [Authorize(Roles="Company")]
 public ActionResult MySecretAction()
 {
     // just companies have accesses to this method
 }
```

Also if both `ApplicationUser` and `Company` classes share lots in common you could just extend `Company` from `ApplicationUser`. By doing so you don't need to write extra login method. Same login works for both. But if for any reason you don't want inherit `Company` from `ApplicationUser` my above solution more desirable.

Comment: but how to do my own _companyManager and how to use Claim for Registration

Comment: It has a simple query to DB actually. To check if a company with provided data is exist or not. Like `db.CompanyAccountModels.Any(c=>c.Name==name && c.Password==password)`

Comment: And also for registration you don't need to do any special thinks. Since we adding necessary climes while user logs in.